# Calculate difference between two rows from two different table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables with the structures as below

table one

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══╗
║ ID ║   Date    ║ value ║  ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══╣
║  1 ║ 1/1/2015  ║   234 ║  ║
║  2 ║ 1/20/2015 ║   267 ║  ║
║  3 ║ 1/25/2015 ║   270 ║  ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══╝
```

second table

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╗
║ start_date ║ end date  ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1/1/2015   ║ 1/20/2015 ║
║ 1/20/2015  ║ 1/25/2015 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╝
```

My output has to be

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ start_date ║ end date  ║ difference ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1/1/2015   ║ 1/20/2015 ║         33 ║
║ 1/20/2015  ║ 1/25/2015 ║          3 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

So here I have to join table number two to table number one based on date and then calculate difference between the two values(that is corresponding to the date) in the column and then display it in one sql query.

Problem is I am not able to join all of them in one query and display them together.

This is what i have s far

```
select start_date, end_date, ((SELECT
                    table_one.value
                FROM
                    table_one, 
                    table_two 
                WHERE 
                    table_one.date= table_two.end_date(+)
                ) - (
                SELECT
                    table_one.value
                FROM
                    table_one, 
                    table_two 
                WHERE 
                    table_one.date = table_two.start_date(+)
                ))from table_two,table_one where table_two.start_date(+)=table_one.date
```

I am getting ORA- 01427 with the above query. What am I doing wrong and how do I achieve the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `join`s:

```
select t2.start_date, t2.end_date, (t1e.value - t1s.value) as difference
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1s
     on t2.start_date = t1s.date join
     table1 t1e
     on t2.end_date = t1e.date;
```

If some dates in `table2` might not match `table1`, then use `left join` instead of inner join.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly..heres the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8fe1/5)  for the above query if anyone needs it.